# Node Js API with postman, how should i git vendor id

Tags: node.js, express

I have sent value in post request with postman to a nodejs api and now i want to get its values.
If i write 
    console.log(req.body);
i get

```
{ 'vendor_medicine_id[]': [ '5b10dc0aa5d60c23a8947e7a', '5b0d4c9abcd16f0558afce85' ],
  'quantity[]': [ '15', '17' ],
  'name[]': [ 'abc', 'xyz' ],
  'contact_number[]': [ '0332695258', '44477889922225' ] }
```

i want to get this value '5b10dc0aa5d60c23a8947e7a', what should i write

```
console.log(req.body.???.???);
```

can you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily like this:

```
console.log(req.body["vendor_medicine_id[]"][0]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes its worked :). Thank you very much @captain jack sparrow

Comment: Great, approve the answer if it solves your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are brackets in the key of the value you want to access, I'd recommend using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) instead of dot notation. After that, you access the first item in the `array` by using `[0]`.

```
console.log(req.body['vendor_medicine_id[]'][0]);
```

If you want to access all values in that array, you might want to use an iteration:

```
req.body['vendor_medicine_id[]'].forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item)
});
```

For more information, see: [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)